# Impulses in a Collision

Tags: collision, computational-physics, simulations

The question I have is that of computing the impulse in a collision between two objects in real life (or in a scenario that is very close to real life). I wish to simulate collisions of objects of varying materials (such as rubber, concrete, marble, etc.)

As an example, suppose I drop a ball onto a table. How high should the ball rebound? The ball would (as I have learned) rebound with a speed corresponding to the impulse. But how much is the impulse?

I would expect a ball made of rubber to rebound higher than a ball made of iron. Is this only because the masses of the ball, or does the strength of the material influence the impulse?

I am more or less looking for an equation that governs the impulses in a collision between two objects, in a system that is not necessarily closed.